# Manipulating property typed as List

Tags: c#, list, properties

I have a Property which is of List Type as below.

```
private List<ListCOP_PAYLOAD> m_COP_DATA = new List<ListCOP_PAYLOAD>();
public List<ListCOP_PAYLOAD> COP_DATA
{
    get
    {
        return m_COP_DATA;
    }
    set
    { 
        m_COP_DATA = value;
        FireNewSMode_Data();
    }
}
```

Each time I add data I use the following:

```
m_exchangedata.COP_DATA = Mstruct.lMCOPStruct;
```

But it just increases the list size with the new data variables.

I want to clear the previous data so I used

```
m_exchangedata.COP_DATA.Clear();
```

**Edited:** 
I use it in this order

```
 m_exchangedata.COP_DATA.Clear();
 m_exchangedata.COP_DATA = Mstruct.lMCOPStruct;
```

but that does not seem to work.

I get InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements.

The FireNewSMode_Data just fires off an event with the data if the event handler is not null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide `FireNewSMode_Data` method?

Comment: `does not seem to work` -> this does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Put a condition of count before clearing the `COP_DATA` list:

```
if(m_exchangedata.COP_DATA.Count > 0)
{
    m_exchangedata.COP_DATA.Clear();
}
m_exchangedata.COP_DATA = Mstruct.lMCOPStruct;
```

Comment: Great comment and I used it earlier in the code. My problem was that both m_exchangedata and Mstruct are reference types so when I was clearing COP_DATA I was also clearing lMCOPStruct. I should have noticed that sooner.